# JQuery wrap each word of string in span if it is not wrapped

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string

```
<div id="title">Lorem <span class="bold">ipsum</span> dolor sit amet</div>
```

I want to wrap each unwrapped word in `#title` container with span. The result must be:

```
<div id="title"><span>Lorem </span><span class="bold">ipsum</span><span> dolor</span><span> sit</span><span> amet</span></div>
```

What I tried and it didn't work correctly - wraps the first word, but displays the last three words in the same `<span>`:

```
$('#title')
        .contents()
        .filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType === 3;
        })
        .wrap( "<span></span>" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the last three words are content of a single text node you can't do it in this way, instead you have to split and wrap the content. You can use [`replaceWith()`](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) method and return an array of HTML content.

```js
$('#title')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  }).replaceWith(function() {
    return this.nodeValue.split(/(?=\b\s)/).map(str => `<span>${str}</span>`)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title">Lorem <span class="bold">ipsum</span> dolor sit amet</div>
```