# JavaScript; wrap each item (word, HTML element or otherwise) in span tags

Tags: javascript

I have a specific use case requiring me to wrap each item of an element in span tags, so whether that be a word, another HTML element or otherwise, I need a way to target them.

The code I have is as follows;

```
var hasTransitionTextReveal = document.getElementsByClassName('has-transition_text-reveal');

for (var i = 0; i < hasTransitionTextReveal.length; i++) {
    var word = hasTransitionTextReveal.item(i);

    word.innerHTML = word.innerHTML.replace(/(^|<\/?[^>]+>|\s+)([^\s<]+)/g, '$1<span class="text-reveal_wrapper"><span class="text-reveal">$2</span></span>');
}
```

This works for the most part, but not when the "hasTransitionTextReveal" element contains nested HTML, e.g. an a tag, another span tag, etc.

I did find the below regex edit which helps a bit more, but still isn't correct;

```
word.innerHTML = word.innerHTML.replace(/(?<!(<\/?[^>]*|&[^;]*))([^\s<]+)/g, '$1<span class="text-reveal_wrapper"><span class="text-reveal">$2</span></span>');
```

Ideally I would like to be able to wrap each word, element, etc., in the span tags.

For example, taking the below code to illustrate my point;

```
<h1 class="has-transition_text-reveal"><small>A <span>lorem-ipsum<sup><ion-icon name="cloudy-outline"></ion-icon></sup></span> dolor sit amet.</small></h1>
```

I would like to have the below outputted as a result;

```
<span class="text-reveal_wrapper"><span class="text-reveal">A</span></span> <span class="text-reveal_wrapper"><span class="text-reveal"><span>lorem-ipsum<sup><ion-icon name="cloudy-outline"></ion-icon></sup></span></span></span> <span class="text-reveal_wrapper"><span class="text-reveal">dolor</span></span>
```

And so on and so fourth.

I've played about with everything listed here, but none are as specific as my use case and so no joy.

[How to wrap each word of an element in a span tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609170/how-to-wrap-each-word-of-an-element-in-a-span-tag)

Perhaps regex isn't the way to go - open to any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: If your HTML is very complex, this will be arbitrarily difficult.  But for many cases you could get away with just splitting on whitespace: `foo.innerHTML = foo.innerHTML.split(' ').map(word => \`<span>${word}</span>\`).join('')` (for each of the DOM nodes you're iterating over.)

Comment: You're right, and perhaps I'm over complicating the issue. Any idea how I can adjust my regex above to 1) allow for the double span with the class names and 2) ignore the HTML elements completely?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to wrap existing HTMLElements, just wrap the TextNodes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        span {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="has-transition_text-reveal">
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At impedit deleniti reprehenderit, cupiditate repellat temporibus, voluptas, recusandae ratione commodi iste quo mollitia ducimus maiores error?
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolar</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <i>amet</i>.</li>
        </ul>
        Tenetur aperiam ducimus quisquam exercitationem! Repellendus voluptas qui quibusdam expedita tempore debitis laborum? Adipisci delectus reprehenderit porro soluta tempore dolor maxime ullam. Impedit odit assumenda quae nihil omnis eos recusandae voluptatum doloremque fugit deserunt soluta mollitia voluptas reprehenderit dignissimos nam porro asperiores tque cum nisi, odio laudantium, commodi consectetur. Iste sequi molestiae quibusdam labore! Nisi voluptatum totam doloremque saepe. Magni laborum pariatur aut excepturi accusantium sapiente illum, repellendus dolores cum rem numquam odio nesciunt enim quasi odit a vel architecto eius optio dolorem est quis. Rerum, illo. Quae reiciendis facere eligendi excepturi ducimus numquam quis temporibus non modi obcaecati eaque, sit labore iure totam qui beatae, a, quod distinctio perferendis quisquam? Consectetur quasi possimus adipisci assumenda. Tempore ratione saepe a nisi tempora deserunt voluptas iure libero voluptatem autem modi perferendis, molestias itaque repudiandae sapiente adipisci quaerat? Similique porro saepe dolorem minima nihil veniam! Quis eos voluptatibus atque asperiores repudiandae, eius velit accusamus laudantium iste odit deleniti, pariatur eligendi vitae, similique tempore amet architecto! Molestias necessitatibus ea inventore modi vitae doloremque optio libero, dolore ex ipsam perferendis provident reiciendis laboriosam aliquid obcaecati ab voluptates porro
    </div>

    <hr />
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, facere.
    </div>
    <hr />

    <div class="has-transition_text-reveal">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, facere.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
const wrapContent = (element) => {
    [...element.childNodes].forEach(node => {
        if(node instanceof HTMLElement) {
            return wrapContent(node);
        } else {
            const str = node.nodeValue.replace(/(\\n|\\r)/, '').trim();
            if (str.length) {         
                const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
                str.split(' ').forEach(word => {
                    const span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.textContent = word;
                    fragment.appendChild(span);
                    fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));
                });
                node.replaceWith(fragment);
            }
        }
    })
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.has-transition_text-reveal')].forEach(container => wrapContent(container))
});
```

Comment: This solution still targets the HTML, however, you might be onto something. Any idea how I can adjust my regex above to 1) allow for the double span with the class names and 2) ignore the HTML elements completely?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm getting closer.

The below code does everything I need it to, however it is removing whitespace and I can't understand why - the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59962805/jquery-wrap-each-word-of-string-in-span-if-it-is-not-wrapped) I worked from managed to keep the whitespace (same regex).

```
$('.has-transition_text-reveal').each(function() {
    $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).replaceWith(function() {
        return this.nodeValue.split(/(?=\b\s)/).map(str => `<span class="text-reveal_wrapper"><span class="text-reveal">${str}</span></span>`)
    });
});
```

Comment: This actually does do what I wanted - CSS is removing the white-space.